# Diff-in-Diff analysing policy affecting parental income that may affect child health

Tags: stata, difference-in-difference

I am interested to see if a particular policy that increases parental income may impact child health for mothers and fathers. So it would be a diff-in-diff model I would be running. Below is my regression model:

$$\text{Children Health}_{it} = \beta_0 + \beta_1Post_t + \beta_2 Treated_i+ \beta_3(Post_t \cdot Treated_{i}) + \beta_4X_{pt} + \varepsilon_{it}$$

Here Post is a dummy for period after policy, Treated is a dummy for those who receive the treatment, and X is a vector of parental controls such as age, gender, qualification, etc. Would my above regression be correct if I ran it separately for mothers and fathers?

I also wondered whether I should include another vector variable controlling for child characteristics such as age and gender.

The code for mothers and fathers separate diff in diff regressions are:

```
regress child_health post#treat mother_age qualification marital status, robust

regress child_health post#treat father_age qualification marital status, robust
```

In addition, I was wondering if there may be more than one child in the household, and I would run this regression for each child, so I was wondering if I have to cluster the standard errors or how I would do this.

Comment: Be aware of multiple testing when running the analysis multiple times for mother's, father's and children

Comment: Could you provide a brief description of what each subscript denotes? I am finding it hard to distinguish between $i$, $h$, and $p$.

Comment: Yes, i is for the child, and p stands for the parents. So It's looking at the impact of the policy that affected the parent's income and how then may affect the child's health.